# Java default access level (package private access). Why it is used for?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Although I know how default (package) access level works in java, I can't imagine its real use in applications except for those with unique package. What do you use default access level for in business (usually multipackage) java applications?

Comment: When you want something restricted to just that package. I'm not sure what different answer could possibly be given here.

Comment: Package private _classes_ are often used for non-public implementations of public interfaces. These can be instantiated in a factory or similar in the same package.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel the duplicate candidate also helped! My purpose was to get answers about use in real world business apps because I already know that package members are restricted to just that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common pattern for using package-private classes is to create *shared* implementations of interfaces or shared subclasses of common classes.

Note that the fact of sharing is important here, because inner classes provide a better alternative for hiding class / interface implementations from the caller.

Another common use is for "utility classes", when you wish to share a group of algorithms "horizontally" among different classes, without exposing these algorithms to outside users of your class library. Various argument checkers fall into this category.

Answer (score 2):

I would use them when client code doesn't need to know the proper class implementing an interface and initializing it through a factory method or builder because the class by itself can be very complex to handle.

E.g.

Interface

```
package foo.bar;

public interface FooBarInterface {
}
```

Implementations of interface

```
package foo.bar;

class FooImpl implements FooBarInterface {
}

package foo.bar;

class BarImpl implements FooBarInterface {
}
```

Factory method:

```
package foo.bar;

public class FooBarInterfaceCreator {
    public static FooBarInterface create(String param) {
        //creates instance based on parameters...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly I've used that access for unit tests. In which case, I've to change some of my *private* methods to give them package access, so as to test them. Of course your unit tests should follow same package structure as your actual code.

Comment: `protected` should also work fine for that.

Comment: @AniketThakur Yeah but that would be visible to subclasses even in different packages.

Comment: @AniketThakur it would work, yes. But it would provide access to subclasses.