# Why we cannot add default for method in class

Tags: java, java-8

If we are not adding any access specifier to method by default it is of default type.

but we are adding `default` keyword then it is giving me error, like we can have default method in interface only. I am aware about the default method in functional interface but strange why it is showing error in eclipse.

```
public class Test
{
    
    default void test() { //Default methods are allowed only in interfaces.
        
    }
}
```

this one is working fine

```
public class Test
{
    void test()
    {
    }
}
```

any reason for it?

Comment: A `class` cannot have a `default` method, just `interface`s can... The comment in your first example literally says this!

Comment: Default methods are only applicable to interfaces

Comment: Why do you think it is strange? As you said, default method can be declared in interfaces only - declaring it normal class results in an error.  That is something I'd expect.

Comment: Is this relevant to your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620127/java-define-a-explicit-package-private-modifier

Comment: Why is it strange to indicate an error when there's an error?

Comment: Ah, now I understand the confusion.

Comment: Note that the `default` keyword as used in interfaces does not have anything to do with access specifiers. It does not mean "default access specifier" but "default implementation".

Comment: So default keyword came after java 8 or we were using it somewhere before ? Because we didnt have default method before java 8

Comment: strange, if someone not aware about something, you will down-vote and close the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `default` keyword has nothing to do with default 'package private' access that derives from not specifying the access. The `default` keyword only applies to interfaces (and not just to functional interfaces), to supply a default implementation in the interface. This is a feature introduced in Java 8 to allow for easier interface evolution.

Overloading the `default` keyword to mean 'package private' access when used in classes would only be confusing and serve no real value, as the same is achieved by **not** specifying access.

Comment: I didn't get it. Let me understand that by asking questions.
What is access specifier for void test(){}

Comment: @sparsh610: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html - There is no access modifier specified, therefor it has the "packave-private" modifier.

Comment: @sparsh610 There is no access specified in that case, so it gets the default access, which is 'package private'. The word 'default' in that case has no relation to the `default` keyword. Similarly, in interfaces, you can use the access specified `public`, but as it is the only valid access specifier, not including the access specifier in interfaces results in the default access, which is 'public'.

Comment: So can i conclude that default keyword came from java 8

Comment: @sparsh610 Yes, the `default` keyword was introduced in Java 8, and the only meaning it has is that the method in the interface defines not just the method, but also its default implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Although it was a small concept and still after having a good experience in Java, i was not aware of same.